# Proving result in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, field-theory

Question:

Using only the axioms of a field, prove that if $x$ is an element of a field, and $ x^3 + x^2 = 0 $, then either $x = 0$ or $x = -1$

My attempt:

If $ x = 0$ then the proof is done.

How do I show that $ x = -1 $ ? I am not sure how to approach and solve this question

Comment: Factorise.$\phantom{}$

Comment: So if $ x^2(x+1) = 0$ then how do I show that $ x = -1$ ?

Comment: You are proving the wrong direction.  You are going from result to premise.  You need to go from premise to result.

Comment: @fleablood, I think that you didn't understand the proof. He's doing it the correct way. If you shall show that $p \vee q$, then you can say "if $p$ then we're done, therefore assume not $p$".

Comment: Yes, I realized that in a comment made in a comment later.  As it is written the wording that that was his intent wasn't very clear.  If x=0 "the proof" is very much far from being done. The "done" in "done" refers to achieving the result.  I misunderstood "if x= 0 then proof is done" to mean "If x then x^3+x^2 = 0" rather than "if x=0 then x=0 or x=-1".  The mistake was on my part.  I also misunderstood do to "how do I show x=-1".  You don't.  It's possible that x could be anything (but if it is not 0 or 1 then x^3+x^2 is not 0). So I took it to mean how do I show x=-1 implies x^2+x^2=0.

Answer (score 0):

So, if $x=0$ - you've established the equality.

Now, suppose $x \neq 0$, hence we are in the field, there exists $x^{-1}$. And you can freely establish, that anything multiplied by $0$ is $0$.

$a \cdot 0 = a \cdot (0 + 0) = a \cdot 0 + a \cdot 0 \Rightarrow a \cdot 0 = 0$

Then,

$(x^{-1})^2 \cdot (x^{3} + x^{2}) = (x^{-1})^2 \cdot 0$

or

$x + 1 = 0 \Rightarrow x = -1$.

Comment: Are we allowed to use $(x^{-1})^2$? Can we multiply by $ x^-1 $ twice?

Comment: I see. The field have no non-trivial(i.e. non zeros by themselves)  zero divisors, so $x^{-1} \cdot x^{-1}$ is not a zero in the settings of $x \neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, prove i) $0*x=0$ and ii) if $xy=0$ then either $x=0$ or $x=0$.

i) $0*x=0*x+0$

$=0*x + (0*x -0*x) $

$=(0*x +0*x)-0*x $

$=(0+0)*x -0*x  $

$=0*x -0*x=0$

ii) if $x\ne 0;y\ne 0$ then

$xy=xy $

$1=(xy)*(y^{-1}x^{-1}) $

If $xy=0$ then $1=(xy)*(y^{-1}x^{-1})=0*(y^{-1}x^{-1})=0$.

That is a contradiction so $xy=0\implies x=0$ or $y=0$.

....

So $x^2 (x+1)=x^3+x^2$

If $x^2 (x+1)=0$ then either $x^2=0$ or $x+1=0$.

If $x^2=x*x=0$ then $x=0$.

If $x+1=0$

$x+1-1=-1$

$x=-1$.

Comment: Could we do it @dEmigOd method? If $ x=0$ then proof is complete. Otherwise we can multiply both sides of equation by multiplicative inverse and show $ x = -1$

Comment: Yes, you could do it his/her way. These are essentially the same.